# What the first byte of DB2 blob stands for?

Tags: java, db2, blob, bson

In my db2 table, there is a blob column used to save BSON. I want to serialize/deserialize it to/from String in java.
The only concern is the first byte is always 0x3, then followed by the length of the bytes.

What does 0x3 stands for? If I hard code it to 0x3, could it breaks in different environment?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you are getting this "first byte". And are you using the built-in BSON2JSON function?

Comment: I would recommend against deserializing BSON values with any logic outside the database engine. The internal format may/will change in the next database upgrade, without notice. Any program you have written will start crashing, without a clear immediate solution but to downgrade the entire database (not great).

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-
I got the byte array from the blob type in java. It is 0x3 followed by the length of the array. After read some BSON docs, I believe 0x3 stands for embedded document. Please correct me if I am wrong.